# Problems installing IDLE2HTML

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

I'm trying to install IDLE2HTML from the following [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IDLE2HTML/0.2) in order to print from IDLE in color. I use Python 2.7 on a Mac.

I follow the instructions from the `readme.txt`, but when I reload IDLE nothing has changed. I don't have the Save As HTML option.

In the past I've installed and reinstalled Python a few times.

When trying to find my `idlelib` folder (as written in the readme instructions), I eventually found it under the path `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/`

Is my problem that my python is in `/System/Library/`?

Any ideas please?

Comment: This might be off topic. IDLE and related installation should be OK, but SO members get a wild hair up their ass on occasion and close for things like "it's being installed for printing". If its closed, try [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or the [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does `which Python` report that Python is installed in this directory?

Comment: When I type "which Python" into the Terminal.app, it returns "/usr/local/bin/python".

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't helpful at all....not sure what I was thinking.  I don't think it matters where Python is installed, only that you've followed the instructions correctly, and copied the file into the correct `idlelib` directory (assuming you have multiple Python installations).

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this extension, but the following may help.  When you start Idle, select File / Path browser on the menu.  You should see

```
_ sys.path
|
+ some_path/pythonxy/Lib/idlelib
|
+ some_path/python27.zip  # or MAC equivalent
```

The first path tells you *where* the new files should be.  If you click the `+`, you will see what file *are* there.  What about IDLE2HTML.py?  The next issue is whether you properly edited config-extensions.def.  If you wait a few days for 2.7.9 and install it, you can try the new Options / Config-extensions dialog on the menu.  That will show whether Idle can read the new information in the .def file.  Or you can edit your question, paste in the new material you added, and comment on this answer, and I will take a look.  However, given that the extension has been around for years, I presume that the addition in config-extensions.txt is correct.

I suspect that whenever you upgrade Python, config-extension.def will be overwritten and you will have to re-edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is not a configuration problem with the IDLE2HTML Python IDLE extension like [this answer (for the same question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27262794/3787376) explains about, it may be a problem with the code itself (this has happened with Python 3 IDLE). This can be checked by running IDLE using the Python file that starts it (`<PYTHON LIBRARY DIR>\idlelib\idle.py` where `<PYTHON LIBRARY DIR>` is the location of the standard library for the Python installation), in a command line interpreter (use `<PYTHON EXECUTABLE DIR>\python.exe` where `<PYTHON EXECUTABLE DIR` is the location of the executable files that start Python). It will launch IDLE and show any errors in the C.L.I..

Quote from Python *idlelib* module docstring:

> Idle includes an interactive shell and editor. Use the files named idle.* to start Idle.

IDLE2HTML real error example:
[image: Example image of IDLE2HTML error shown in C.L.I. - https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Yca.png]

A common problem is that IDLE2HTML **version 2.0** (latest at time of writing) needs a simple **code tweak to work with Python 3**.x (a fixed version that works as part of the [IDLEX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net/extensions.html) Python module had this tweak). File comparison image (left is original file, right is IDLEX version in image); if the Python version is Python 3.x, `import Tkinter` needs to be changed to `import tkinter as Tkinter` and `import tkFileDialog` needs to be changed to `import tkinter.filedialog as tkFileDialog`:
[image: The image described above.]

Answer (score 1):

Edwards suggestion of using the `CLI` for diagnosis was very useful. It exposed that the cgi.escape attribute does not exist for `Python 3`.

I changed the `IDLE2HTML.py` line 74 from "`out.append(cgi.escape(content))`" to
"`out.append(content)`" and after a re-boot it all worked!

Later: well almost... better to replace "import cgi" with "import html and then cgi.escape() with html.escape()

If using `Win10` you will need super-admin rights to change `IDLE2HTML`.